# Make a link pass extra information to a JSP

Tags: jsp

I want to do something like this:

```
<a href="myJSPFile" onClick="request.setAttribute("special case")"> click here </a>
```

Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the querystring.

```
<a href="myJSPFile?specialCase=imSpecial">click here</a>
```

Then read it with

```
request.getParameter("specialCase");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put all information in a session which then would be better if the browser closes unexpectedly. Some sample code:
In the first page when the user clicks.

```
session.setAttribute("nameOfAttribute", informationForAttribute);
```

To retrieve the information:

```
session.getAttribute("nameOfAttribute")
```

This would then mean you can have a cleaner URL as you don't have to place query strings in the URL.

Here is a useful [link](http://www.jsptut.com/Sessions.jsp) on sessions.